# No module named 'version' during building package

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pip

I'm trying to build a custom python package, with `pyproject.toml`. I added a `setup.py` just for a development and editable environment. (see https://snarky.ca/what-the-heck-is-pyproject-toml/)
`pyproject-toml` file :

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools == 44.1.1", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = ["tests"]
```

I upgraded python build with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade build`

When i run `python3 -m build` I get this error :

```
...
Successfully installed setuptools-44.1.1 wheel-0.36.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    setuptools.setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
    dist.parse_config_files()
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_virtualenv.py", line 21, in parse_config_files
    result = old_parse_config_files(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 701, in parse_config_files
    parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 121, in parse_configuration
    meta.parse()
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 426, in parse
    section_parser_method(section_options)
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 399, in parse_section
    self[name] = value
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 184, in __setitem__
    value = parser(value)
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 515, in _parse_version
    version = self._parse_attr(value, self.package_dir)
  File "/tmp/build-env-qw5973cj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 349, in _parse_attr
    module = import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'

ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel
```

I don't understand the source of the error, which seems to not have a link with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People usually set the variable `__version__` in a module, a file named `version.py`, to specify the version informattion and make it available to the world to inspect, see [pep-0396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) for detailed explanation. So the traceback might indicate the lack of version file in your package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it read setup.py (or setup.cfg etc.) when building pyproject.toml (only using setuptools as [build-system]??) .

Might you write "from version import **version**" something else in your setup.py?

delete setup.py or rename setup.py to setup__.py, for example.

My Env.

- setuptools: 67.6.0

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools_scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```